# lattice levelplot only fails under RApache

Tags: php, r, curl, rapache

I'm working on a PHP web app that calls R through curl and RApache.  Most things work fine. But one lattice plot throws this error:

> RApache Warning/Error!!!Error in uy +
>   c(-1, 1) : non-numeric argument to
>   binary operator

I tried saving the data structures that feed into the plot and doing the plot in my local R, but then the plot works just fine. So I can't replicate the error.

These are the loaded libraries when the script runs in RApache:

```
library(Brew)
library(Cairo)
library(rjson)
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
library('RColorBrewer')
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(hexbin)
```

Here is a bit of the script:

```
colgrad.pal<-colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral'), interpolate='spline')

//problem plot
dists.med.lplot<-levelplot(value~starttime+groupname|dists, data=MDist.median,
  col.regions=rev(colgrad.pal(200)),colorkey=list(col=rev(colgrad.pal(200))),
  xlab='Time(s)',ylab='Treatment',
  main='Level Plot of Median Distance',
  layout=c(1,3))
```

<del>And here is a link to a datafile.  I read it in like this:</del> //link appears untrustworthy, so removed

Data looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   2880 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ groupname: Factor w/ 8 levels "rowA","rowB",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ fCycle   : Factor w/ 6 levels "Cycle 1","Cycle 2",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ fPhase   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Dark","Light": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ starttime: int  0 60 120 180 240 300 360 420 480 540 ...
 $ dists    : Factor w/ 3 levels "inadist","lardist",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value    : num  47.5 64 78.3 39.2 53.7 ...
```

Any ideas on what the problem is or how to better troubleshoot this?

ETA version/platform info

```
        [platform] => sparc-sun-solaris2.10
        [arch] => sparc
        [os] => solaris2.10
        [system] => sparc, solaris2.10
        [status] => 
        [major] => 2
        [minor] => 10.1
        [year] => 2009
        [month] => 12
        [day] => 14
        [svn rev] => 50720
        [language] => R
        [version.string] => R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14)
```

Comment: What version(s) of R, RApache, and what OS are you using?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: R version 2.10.1, probably RApache 1.1.9 (no dates on the distro, but it was the most recent at the end of this July), OS Solaris2.10

Comment: could you get a traceback of the error somehow? On a sidenote, the safety report of Norton on your link is rather worrying... http://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=filebin.ca Don't know if it's a real risk in your file or just a general idea they have from the site, but it's worth looking at.

Comment: @Joris Meys: that's disturbing about the file.  My local version is just a .csv and doesn't raise any alarms.  I will look for another file dump site, and remove the offending link.

Comment: I check the file itself, and your file doesn't give anything. Hence, problem is the site. I checked a bit further, and apparently it's a problem with malicious files hosted somewhere else on filebin.ca. FWIW, I use dropbox (www.dropbox.com) for file sharing (among other things). Tried a lot of ways, but after setting this up I never looked for anything else again. It's worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error smells of an issue with your data.  I would try the following:

- before the actual call to `plot()` et al, save all your (relevant) data via `save(x, y, z, ..., file="/tmp/dbg.RData"`)
- then load all the relevant data from the saved file in a 'normal' R session and inspect and compare
- this should allow you to pinpoint a data issue that you may then be able to circumvent with more sanity checks etc to prevent your actual code from falling over.

Comment: That's excellent advice.  I had 'saved' the data with `write.table(MDist.median ,file=fn,row.names=F)`. The file produced by `write.table()` gives no errors when processed in 'normal' R.  But using the `save()` method reproduces the error exactly. Strange thing is, the resulting data frames look the same to me.

Comment: It appears that the `save()`d data.frame did not consider the first column a factor, but the `write.table()`d data.frame did.  So I changed the code to explicitly set the factors for my data.frame and now everything works!

Comment: Sweet. Glad to have been of help.